# Extend promise with extra data

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm using `kriskowal/q` promise library to handle http requests, but to simplify the case, let's assume I have an array of promises created dynamically and pushed to the `promises` array:

```
var promises = [],
    ids = ['foo', 'bar', 'buz'];

ids.forEach(function(id){
  var promise = Q.fcall(function () {
    return 'greetings with ' + id;
  });

  promises.push(promise);
});

// and handle all of them together:
Q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
  console.log(results);
});

// gives:
[ 'greetings with foo',
  'greetings with bar',
  'greetings with buz' ]
```

The question is - is it possible to assign somehow an `id` to the promise to obtain it later in `all` execution ?

Let's assume that we cannot modify the returned value (it comes from the API and I cannot extend it with extra data).

Comment: `Promise.all` [guarantees the order of results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28066851/2806996), so can you use the index of each element in `results` to look up the id (trivially in your example)?

Comment: @joews ...aaand the problem is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Now with correct link - my comment referred to ES6 `Promise.all`, but `Q.all` makes the same guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q.all` [guarantees result order](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall), so you can use the index of each element in `results` to look up the id. In your example:

```
Q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
  results.forEach(function(results, i) {
    var id = ids[i];
  })
});
```