# Can this strange behavior with let and var be explained?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

The following example code confuses me...

```
"use strict";

var filesToLoad = [ 'fileA','fileB','fileC' ];
var promiseArray = [];

for( let i in filesToLoad ) {
  promiseArray.push(
    new Promise( function(resolve, reject ) {
      setTimeout( function() {
        resolve( filesToLoad[i] );
      }, Math.random() * 1000 );
    })
  );
}

Promise.all( promiseArray ).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

The reason I'm confused is that I was expecting a random ordered output on the console. But I always get the following...

> [ 'fileA', 'fileB', 'fileC' ]

That confuses me little to say the least, but what really gets me scratching my head is when I change the **let i** to **var i** I get the following result....

> [ 'fileC', 'fileC', 'fileC' ]

As someone who has only recently tried to fully understand Promises and not that long ago starting using let, I'm really stumped.

Further reading...

After getting lots of great answers I have refactored the example to get rid of the loop and *i*. Will seem obvious to most, but fun for me...

```
"use strict";

var filesToLoad = [ 'fileA','fileB','fileC' ];

function start( name )  {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject ) {
      setTimeout( function() {
        resolve( name + '_done' );
      }, Math.random() * 1000 );
    });
}

Promise.all( filesToLoad.map(start) ).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has answered. It's really helping to understand.

Comment: This is a very popular question on SO: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Answer (score 4):

It is because of closure. Read about it [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Also `let` is block scoped whereas `var` is function scoped.

In case of using `var i`:

After timeout when the function is triggered, looping was completed and i was set to 2. so it got resolved with `filesToLoad[2]` for all the setTimeout functions.

In case of using `let i`:

Since it is block scoped, when function is resolved it remembers the state of i when `setTimeOut` was declared, so when it gets resolved it uses correct value of i.

Regarding the order of output in case of using let i.

```
Promise.all(Iterable<any>|Promise<Iterable<any>> input) -> Promise
```

Given an Iterable(arrays are Iterable), or a promise of an Iterable, which produces promises (or a mix of promises and values), iterate over all the values in the Iterable into an array and return a promise that is fulfilled when all the items in the array are fulfilled. The promise's fulfillment value is an array with fulfillment values at respective positions to the original array. If any promise in the array rejects, the returned promise is rejected with the rejection reason.

So irrespective of order in which your promises gets resolved, the result of promise.all will always have promise resolve value in correct order.

Answer (score 2):

**Why using `let` and `var` produces different results:**

The reason that using `let` produces the desired result over `var` is that when using `let` you declare a [block-scoped variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), such that when the loop moves to another iteration the value of `i` remains unaffected for the contents of the loop at that time.

Defining a `var` variable in the header of a for-loop does not mean that it exists only for the life of the for-loop, as you will notice if you do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { /*...*/ }

console.log(i); //=> 10

// `i` is already declared and its value will be 10
for (; i < 20; i++) { /*...*/ }

console.log(i); //=> 20
```

You can avoid this problem altogether if you use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which does the job of `filesToLoad[i]` for you by giving you the next value within a callback function on each iteration:

```
filesToLoad.forEach((file) => {
  promiseArray.push(
    new Promise( function(resolve, reject ) {
      setTimeout( function() {
        resolve( file );
      }, Math.random() * 1000 );
    })
  );
});
```

______

**Does using either `let` or `var` affect the behaviour of `Promise#all`?**

No. In your example, the position of the Promises in `promiseArray` defines in what order the values are added to the results array, not when each of those Promises is resolved. The fact that you resolve the Promises at random intervals does not *move* the position of the resolved value within `promiseArray`. What you have demonstrated is that `Promise#all` produces an array of values whose positions are mapped to the Promise that produced their value.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066851/2039244) for more information about the behaviour of `Promise#all`:

> All this means that **the output is strictly ordered as the input as long as the input is strictly ordered (for example, an array).**

Comment: Your example can be even more concise with `Array.prototype.map`: `const promiseArray = filesToLoad.map(file => new Promise(/**/));`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Thanks :) I favoured familiarity with the original example over introducing new concepts for the sake of OP's understanding. (But you're absolutely right!)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `var`'s scope isn't a child of `for`, it's a sibling. So the loop runs once and sets `i = 0`. It then runs another 2 more times and sets `i = 1` and then `i = 2`. After this has all happened, the timeouts then run and all run the resolve function and passes in `resolve( filesToLoad[2] )`. `let` works correctly because the value of `let i` is not overridden by the following loop iterations.

In short, the timeout only runs after the loop has already run 3 times and therefore passes in the same value. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnvopyoL/) of a working version using `var`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the difference between `let` and `var`. Your issue is not directly related to Promises (besides the fact that they run async).

---

**TL;DR**

`var` declarations are moved to beginning of function by interpreter, so when timeouts executed the loop has already run to end of array on the same variable. `let` keeps the variable in scope, so each iteration of the loop used a different variable.

---

**Background:**

Javascript has a feature called **[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)**, which means that a variable or function is always declared at the beginning of it's wrapping function. If the coder doesn't, the interpreter moves it. Hence:

```
var i;
for (i in array)
....
```

and

```
for (var i in array)
....
```

are equivalent, even though, having some reason, or other programming background, you would expect `i` to be scoped to the loop alone in the second case.

That's why

```
alert(i);
...
var i=5;
```

alerts `undefined` instead of throwing an error. As far as the interpreter is concerned - there was a declaration. It's like

```
var i;
alert(i);
...
i=5;
```

---

**Now:**

ES6/ES2015 has introduced `let` - which behaves as our first assumption in the second example above.

```
alert(i);
...
let i=5;
```

will actually throw an error. When reaching the `alert` there is no `i` to speak of.

---

**In your case**

With `let` you went through the loop with a new variable each time, since `let` was defined only to scope of the loop. Each iteration is a scope, each used a different variable (though all named `i` in their respective scopes)

When using `var`, you actually declared `i` *before* the loop

```
var i;
for( i in filesToLoad ) {
  promiseArray.push(
    new Promise( function(resolve, reject ) {
      setTimeout( function() {
        resolve( filesToLoad[i] );
      }, Math.random() * 1000 );
    })
  );
}
```

so it's the same variable on each iteration (or, in each scope), meaning that the loop assigned the last item to `i` before any of the timeouts returned. That's why the result was 3 times the last item.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually two different, unrelated problems.

Your first observation, that the output is in the original order, rather than a random order, is due to the behaviour of `Promise.all`. `Promise.all` returns a new promise that resolves to an array when all sub-promises have resolved, in the original order. You can think of it like `Array.map`, but for promises.

As stated in [the Bluebird (a JS promise library) documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html):

> The promise's fulfillment value is an array with fulfillment values at respective positions to the original array.

Your second problem, how changing `let` to `var` changes the output to have all of the same values, is due to array scoping. Put simply, a variable defined with `var` exists *outside* of the `for` loop scope. This means that on each iteration, you are actually modifying the value of the pre-existing variable, as opposed to creating a new variable. Since your code inside the Promise executes later, the variable will have the value from the last loop iteration.

`let` creates a variable that exists *inside* that `for` iteration. This means that, later on in the Promise, you are accessing a variable defined *in that iterations scope*, which isn't overridden by the next loop iteration.