# Glitch with node.js promises copying values

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a react application interacting with a drop wizard REST API. In my code I noticed the following odd bug.

In attempting to set the values of two variable and then use them to set state, I had the following

```
const [inventorRes, sellerRes] =
await Promise.all([
    LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Inventory Owner'),
    LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Seller'),
]);
```

where LoginTransport is a method that calls the external API. Now I noticed that in doing this, both inventor res and sellerRes would be set to the value of LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Inventory Owner') as opposed to the respective arguments.

When I break it up into:

```
const inventorRes = await LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Inventory Owner');
const sellerRes = await LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Seller');
```

The behavior is correct.

My understanding from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all was that Promise.all returned back an iterable. Is not the case that javascript would attempt to match the values on the left-hand iterable with the right hand? And assuming that's true but I insisted on using Promise.all() how could I accomplish the task I want to do?

Comment: a dumbed down version of your code runs just fine - https://jsfiddle.net/pjh7djx8/ - perhaps your `LoginTransport.getAllUsers` function is broken in some way where running it twice conceptually "at the same time" breaks it

Comment: The behavior you're describing shouldn't be happening. You should check whether `LoginTransport.getAllUsers` has some side-effect that causes it to return the same value if it's called in quick succession. You could check it like this: `const p1 = LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Inventory Owner');
const p2 = LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Seller'); const inventorRes = await p1; const sellerRes = await p2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I noticed that in doing this, both inventor res and sellerRes would be set to the value of `LoginTransport.getAllUsers('Inventory Owner')` as opposed to the respective arguments.

That would be the fault of `LoginTransport.getAllUsers`. [`Promise.all` does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066825/1048572) what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: I see giong to look into it