# Promise with nodejs, how could I chain results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I am using mongodb with mongoose.

I have the some collections with the next models:

a. Model: Product

b. Model: Details

I need return a dataset with the total items in Product, and to each product item, i need calculate the quantity by loop your details in Model Details.

My problem is how do I could set the quantity in my data array, after execute the "promise_3". 
I´d need to know the index of the data array to do it, but How could I do it?

The result will be something as:

```
response:{
total:1012, 
data:[
{id:'1',name:'xx', quantity:10},
{id:'2',name:'yy', quantity:110},
{id:'3',name:'zz', quantity:130},
...
]}
```

//my code with the promises

```
var response={};
var promise_1=Product.count({}).lean().exec();

var prommise_2=function (data){
       return Product.find(conditions)
        .limit(pageSize)
        .skip(pageSize*(pageNumber-1))
        .sort(oorder)
        .lean()
        .exec();
   }


var prommise_3= function (item){
        return Details.aggregate(
                    [
                            { "$match": { 
                                cod_material: item._id
                            }},
                            {$lookup:
                              {
                                from: "estoqueMov", //use the name of database collection not mongoose model
                                localField: "cod_mov",
                                foreignField: "_id",
                                as: "mov_doc"
                              }
                            },

                            { $unwind: "$mov_doc" },
                            {$lookup:
                              {
                                from: "Details", //use the name of database collection not mongoose model
                                localField: "mov_doc.cod_tipo_mov",
                                foreignField: "_id",
                                as: "tipo_mov_doc"
                              }
                            },

                            { $unwind: "$tipo_mov_doc"},
                            { "$group": {
                                _id: "$cod_material",
                                total: { "$sum": 
                                        {"$multiply": 
                                         ["$quantidade",{"$cond":[
                                         {"$eq":["$tipo_mov_doc.tipo","Entrada"]} , 1,-1]}] 
                                        }
                                        } 
                            }}

                    ]);
    }

    //promise_1 is done
    promise_1.then( function(count){
         response.total=count;
         return promise_2() 
    })
    .then( function (data){
        response.data=data;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
          var item=response.data[i];
          //??item.quantity=0;
          return promise_3(item) 
        }
    })
    .then( function (results){
        var total=results.length>0?results[0].total:0;
        //Here is my problem How could I set the response.data index array??
        response.data[??????].quantity=total;
        callback(null,response,res);

    });
```

Comment: In the second callback, you `return` from the middle of your `for` loop. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @ Bergi, I need calculate the quantity to each product item using promise_3. My intent was create a loop and call promise_3. Do you could suggest something different?

Comment: Well either you generate an array of `promise_3` promises, use `Promise.all`, and then iterate the `results` in pretty much the same way (the order is preserved, so you can easily use the indices into the data array). Or you put those `.then()` calls inside the loop, so that every `promise_3` has its own callback (which then can use the index by closure [provided that the loop scope is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)). In any case, drop or move that `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this snippet, you should utlize [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
Since what you're trying to do is actually resolve 1 promise for each item inside your the array.

```
.then( function (data){
        response.data=data;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
          var item=response.data[i];
          //??item.quantity=0;
          return promise_3(item) 
        }
    })
```

It will look something like this

```
 .then( function (data){
            var promises = [];
            response.data=data;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
              var item=response.data[i];
              //??item.quantity=0;
              promises.push(promise_3(item)); 
            }
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
```

Now essentially your next `.then` will not run until all promises in the `promises` array have been resolved.

**NOTE:** Order of the resulting `promise.all` array does maintain it's element order after completely resolving.

Given that the last `.then` will now be getting an array of data you will want to wrap its functionality inside a loop-- something like this (not 100% sure if this is what you want it to do, but you should get the idea.):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var total=results[i].length>0?results[i].total:0;
          response.data[i].quantity=total; 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. It solves a part of the problem. Any suggestion to the last "then" in:  response.data[??????].quantity=total;

Comment: @LuizAlves "chain it again". The answer here does `return Promise.all()` so it returns as a `Promise`, which means you just continue the chain using `.then()`. That's the point. It actually even says *"Now essentially your next `.then()` will not run until all promises in the promises array have been resolved."*

Comment: @ Neil Lunn  OK, I already have a chain in the last step. My problem is that I need to set response.data[index].quantity=total and I don't have this "index" from return of Promisse.All

Comment: @88jayto Hi, Is the index of "results" the same of "response.data"? I think it can be different because promise.all runs all promises in parallel and there is no guaranty about order in the results. Am I correct?

Comment: @LuizAlves There is a guarantee of the order of the elements within the array.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values

You may be thinking of the order in which the promises resolve, which is not guaranteed, but that's unrelated and shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: Thank  you very much Mr 88jayto. I will try with the code now.