# Chaining axios request

Tags: javascript, redux, axios

**The problem**

I am using axios to post multiple request to an API, the order these request reach the API is important. Even though the requests are been sent in the correct order, they are been handled in the wrong order on the API layer (response is been sent back in the incorrect order).

e.g. i send request A and then B, but received the response B first and then A.

**What i am doing currently**

```
const requests = request.map(req => {

  return post<void>(url, params)
    .then(response => {
       console.log(`response sent`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.log(`Response not sent`, err);
    });

});

await Promise.all(requests);
```

Comment: refer [Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values) this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: just put B req in `then` of A!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
const [first, ...others] = request

const makeRequest = ({ url, params }) => post<void>(url, params)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(`response sent`)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`Response not sent`, err)
  })

const requests = others.reduce((promise, req) => {
  return promise.then(() => makeRequest(req))
}, makeRequest(first))

await requests
```

This will chain each request onto the previous request, if it was successful.

**Note:** I'm making the assumption that `url`  and `params` are values on the requests as I can't see in your code where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create strictly ordered array to solve your issue.
refer [Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values)

Comment: how do you know if an array is strictly ordered? Secondly i don't think i've made myself clear. If i send request A first, then B, it is important I know A has been handled by the API before I send request B.

Comment: for example if i did, await post<void>(ApiPaths, params) etc. This would ensure that the response has been received before posting the next request.