# Will the order of responses be the same as the order of the urls in my case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch-api

**QUESTION:**

After looking at this:

[Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values)

I am not certain it applies to my case. Will `responses` always be in the same order as `urls` ?

---

**CODE:**

```
var urls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
     urls.push('someURL/'+enemies[i].id);
}

let promises = urls.map(url => fetchJSON(url, region));

Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
      //DO SOMETHING HERE WITH RESPONSES WHERE ORDER IS IMPORTANT
});


function fetchJSON(url, region) {
    return fetch(url, {
        region: region,
        headers: { 
            'token': apiKey
        }
    }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: yes.

Explanation:

`Array.map` returns an array of promises, the index of each promise in the array corresponds to the index of the URL in `urls` array.

`Promise.all` returns an array of the result of `resolve`s of the `promises` array, the index of each result in the `responses` corresponds to the index of the corresponding promise in `promises` array.

Comment: Thank you. That was the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's one of the guarantees that `Promise.all` provides. From [MDN's page on `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> **Return value**
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - A pending Promise in all other cases. This returned promise is then resolved/rejected asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty) when all the promises in the given iterable have resolved, or if any of the promises reject. See the example about "Asynchronicity or synchronicity of Promise.all" below. **Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.**

*(my emphasis)*

*(Also covered by [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise.all) of course, but...the spec is tricky to read.)*

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Return_value

> Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

So the answer is yes. Also, it would be trivial to contrive a test using setTimeout and independently verify that order is maintained.