# How to avoid using two loops when using Promise.all() dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Whenever you see Promise.all() being used, it is usually used with two loops, how can I make it into only one **without using async** and **mantaining execution order**?

The question is not about the order, I know promise.all preserves order, the question is about how to avoid two loops when you just need the returned value

```
function timeout(x){
 return new Promise( resolve => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    return resolve(x);
  },x)
 })
}

const promises = [];
const results = [];
//First loop, array creation
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  const promise = timeout(i*100)
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then( resolvedP => {
    //Second loop, async result handling
    resolvedP.forEach( (timeout,i) => {
    results.push({
      index : i,
      timeout : timeout
    })
  })
  console.log(results);
})
//End of code
```

Now, this can be solved with `async` but in my context I can't use it, for example :

```
//Only one loop
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const timeoutAwait = await timeout(i*100);
  results.push({
      index : i,
      timeout : timeoutAwait
    })
}
console.log(results)
//End of code
```

What I have tried is the following, but the promise doesn't return the `resolve` value without using `.then()` :

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
  const promise = timeout(i*100)
  promises.push(promise);
  results.push({index : i, timeout : promise});
}

Promise.all(promises).then( resolvedP => {
    resolvedP.forEach( (timeout,i) => {
      results.push({
        index : i,
        timeout : timeout
      })
    })
    console.log(results);
    //results[0].timeout is a Promise object instead of 0
})
//End of code
```

So, is there any way I can make my first code sample in only one loop? Please ignore the context, is only an example.

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with it? Maybe `Promise.all(promises).then(res => res.map((timeout, index) => ({ timeout, index })))` ?

Comment: not sure how you would do it without two loops since you have a loop to create the multiple calls and a loop to handle all the responses when they come back...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need `Promise.all` here? For example, because you want to save the execution/handling of the promises for later? Because otherwise you could just use the `then` method for each promise in the for loop.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I'm not sure, I thought promise.all was needed to maintain execution order

Comment: Define what you mean by "execution order." If you're trying to avoid race conditions, then don't use `Promise.all` since it more or less runs all the promises simultaneously, not in sequence. If you just need to have an array that's lined up, then you don't *really* need `Promise.all`, just make use of the indices that are passed in. But based on your code I'm seeing sort of an XY problem starting to show.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I just need the array to be lined up, not actually executed in sequence

Comment: Ok then I believe ponury-kostek 's answer should work for you.

Comment: The order should already be preserved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066851/457268

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `async` keyword?

Comment: @k0pernikus I'm forced to use a private framework built on top of dojo 1.7 and it just does not play nicely with async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function timeout(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(x);
    }, x);
  });
}

const promises = [];
const results = [];
//First loop, array creation
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const promise = timeout(i * 100).then(x => results.push({
    index: i,
    timeout: x
  }));
  promises.push(promise);
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

If you want to preserve execution/results order assign results using `i` index instead of `.push`

```
const promise = timeout(i * 100).then(x => results[i] = {
  index: i,
  timeout: x
});
```

Comment: Will this guarantee execution order? In this case using timeout it will obviously be in order, but you're already calling then so I don't see why promise.all is necessary.

Comment: @Mojimi `Promise.all` is necessary to wait for all promises to finish

Answer (score 1):

As by the [`Promise.all` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), the order will be preserved. It says about the return value:

> A pending Promise in all other cases. This returned promise is then
>   resolved/rejected asynchronously (as soon as the stack is empty) when
>   all the promises in the given iterable have resolved, or if any of the
>   promises reject. See the example about "Asynchronicity or
>   synchronicity of Promise.all" below. **Returned values will be in order
>   of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.**

(Highlighted by me.)

Answer (score 0):

I find it more easy to understand if you map over an array of values instead of looping:

```js
const timeout = x=>Promise.resolve(x);

Promise.all(
  [...new Array(3).keys()]//array [0,1,2]
    .map(x=>timeout(x*100))//[timeout(0*100),timeout(1*100),...
).then(
  result=>result.map(//results of the timeout, map to object
    (timeout,index)=>({
      index,
      timeout
    })
  )
).then(
  result=>console.log('result:',result)
)
```

It's usually not a good idea to asynchronously mutate a shared variable (the results array). Just have the promise resolve and create the result you need in the last `.then`, now your promise resolves to the value you want.

Comment: Well, map being called twice still counts as two loops, I think ponury-kostek's answer nailed what I was missing

Comment: @Mojimi I added a little more explanation. You have to loop twice over it. First to get map to timeout and then map the result values of timeout to objects. This answer was added to point out that you should avoid the loops and asynchronous mutation of a shared variable in the loops.