# Async.forEach runs in parallel but it is losing the sort order in the original array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to iterate over a collection in parallel and I was using async.forEach() for it, but I need to maintain the sort order too.

```
async.forEach(books, function (book, bookCallback) {
        findBook(account, userinfo, permission, function (error, foundBook) {
            if (error) {
                bookCallback(error);
            } else if (foundBook) {
                bookCallback(account);
                bookCallback(null);
            } else {
                bookCallback(null);
            }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, finaCallback);
        }
    });
```

I have tried with async.map, async.groupBy, but even they did not maintain sort order.
Only when I tried async.eachSeries order was maintained but it was not running in parallel.

Comment: Why do it in parallel if you need control over execution order?

Comment: By sort order you mean execution order ? If yes, running in parallel won't be the solution then.

Comment: @darksmurf The collection is huge and internally its another API call so I need to run that in parallel

Comment: @FarhanTahir Yes I am not worried about execution order. But I am worried about order is not maintained in books array. Before this method call this array had say ['Book1','Book2','Book3'] order, but after this call ends my books array is['Book1','Book3','Book2']. I want sorted in array to be maintained.

Comment: Please be more explicit by what you mean by _sort order_. Are you saying that you need to process the result callback in order? Or that you need to execute the functions in order? By running the functions in parallel, there is no guarantee of any ordering whatsoever.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg So as per your comments my understanding is , it is impossible to maintain the sort order in books array if I want to iterate over the collection in parallel. I should stick to async.eachSeries?

Comment: Not exactly. If the ordering of the result array is all you need, then you can use standard async functions and native Promises to achieve this. Writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want [`async.parallel`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) in this case, but you basically need to transform your input to that first:

```
let tasks = [ ...accounts.entries() ].map(([k, account]) =>
  ({ 
    [k]: (callback) => findbook(account, userinfo, permission, callback)
  })
);

async.parallel(tasks, (err,results) => {
    if (err) throw err;          // error handling of some sort
    // reconstruct array order by index position
    results = accounts.map((e,i) => results[i])
})
```

Alternately, you can wrap your method that accepts a callback with a `Promise` and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which is parallel and [respects the same order in results as the input used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values):

```
Promise.all(
  accounts.map(account => new Promise((resolve,reject) => 
    findbook(account, userinfo, permission, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(result)
    })
  ))
).then(results => {
  // results have original order
}).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which library `async` is coming from, but assuming you are using a modern version of node, you don't need a special library to handle async calls. Here's what you can do:

```
async function getBooks() {
  let result = await Promise.all(books.map(book => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      findBook(account, userinfo, permission, function (error, foundBook) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else if (foundBook) {
          resolve(account);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });  
    });
  return result;
}
```

And `result` will be an array of results in the same order of the original `books` array.

The `getBooks` function returns a promise that is either rejected or resolved. If I understand your problem correctly, this should solve it.

Comment: @ AndrewEisenberg I will surely try this now, but before that I just wondering that iteration over books collection is in parallel right?

Comment: Yes. All requests are sent in parallel.