# What is the flow of the code in promise and order of their execution?

Tags: javascript, function

In the below code in `Promise` there are three function calls. How are those functions executed; in parallel or in series?

```
return Promise.all([
  getUserData({ req }),
  getNetworkServiceCountsData({ req }),
  getShelfServiceCountsData({ req }),
])
```

Comment: Two functions cannot run at the same time. Javascript is not multithreading language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three functions are executed in the order you have put them. But these functions could make use of some asynchronous request (e.g. a http-request), and JavaScript does not block execution for awaiting the response of such requests. Instead these functions typically have a listener in place for an event that bubbles up from the lower, operating system layers, and they *immediately* return a promise without awaiting such events.

So the first function triggers a request and returns a promise, then the second function does the same, and then third. We then have three unresolved promises that are passed to `Promise.all` which also returns an unresolved promise.

Then the waiting starts...

The processing of these asynchronous requests could happen at a different layer, possibly even on a different server, some database or web service. Typically, such processing can be parallel, as it is not restricted by the single-threaded JavaScript engine. That processing eventually results in an event in the JavaScript event queue. The event listeners that I mentioned before are called by the JS event loop and those handlers resolve the corresponding promises.

As the processing for the three tasks could have different durations, the order of the promise resolutions is not guaranteed.

But when all three promises are resolved (whatever their order of resolution), the promise that was returned by `Promise.all` will also resolve.

So, yes, things will run in parallel, but not the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Execution is parallel but the values in results are in the same order as the promises.

Also It will return a promise once all the promises are resolved. If any one of the promise is failed it will reject immediately with the error value of the promise that is rejected regardless of whether the remaining promises are resolved or not.

You can find reference links below for better understanding:

https://medium.com/@muralikv/implementing-promise-all-in-javascript-732076497946

[Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values)