# Issues refactoring async function call on each object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, eslint

I need to fetch all direct reports for the logged in manager and then display a card component for each one. I have to make a separate async call `getPhoto(id)` for each report by iterating over the response array of employee objects.

The following is my original attempt, which after running `eslint`, I realized is inefficient due to the sequential `await`'s inside the `for...of` loop.

```
async function getReports() {
  const response = await fetch('/current_user_direct_reports')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.value)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

  for (const report of response) {
    report.photo = await getPhoto(report.userPrincipalName);
  }

  setReports(response)
}

useEffect(() => {
  getReports();
}, []);
```

This works but is rather slow. I tried adjusting the code to collect a list of employee objects, each containing a photo `Promise`, in order to allow all requests to resolve simultaneously.

```
async function getReports() {
  const response = await fetch('/current_user_direct_reports')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data.value)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

  const reportsAndPhotos = [];
  for (const report of response) {
    const emp = report;
    emp.photo = getPhoto(report.userPrincipalName);
    reportsAndPhotos.push(emp);
  }

  return (await Promise.all(reportsAndPhotos));
}

useEffect(() => { 
  async function getEmployees() {
    const reportsAndPhotos = await getReports();
    setReports(reportsAndPhotos);
    setLoaded(true);
  }
  getEmployees();
}, []);
```

However, my response is repeatedly rendered empty and I cannot identify what I'm doing wrong. I thought `Promise.all()` would wait for everything to resolve before returning.

Comment: `emp.photo` is the promise, so `Promise.all([emp, emp, …])` where `emp` isn’t a promise doesn’t make sense.

Comment: `Promise.all()` expects an array of promises, not an array of objects with properties that are promises. To say what @Ry- said a little differently :).

Comment: Ah, thank you both! Now my question is - if I were to adjust to pull back only photos and use `Promise.all()` on that array, how can I maintain the connection between an employee and their specific photo? Since of course I wouldn't be able to trust the order in which they were fetched

Comment: @jasonkylemorse Doesn't matter when the fetch responses arrive, you [can trust the order of the `Promise.all` results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066825/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Perfect, thank you very much for the info!