# How do I use $q.all(promises) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Usually I would do

```
$http({
    method:'GET',
    url: 'exmapleURL',
    params: {someParams}
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // response contains data I need
});
```

Now I have multiple such calls to run and I would like to wait for all of them to finish before doing something with their responses, and $q.all() seems to be a good place to start.

Per the [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) document,

> ### all(promises)
>
> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.
> **Returns:** Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

Does this mean that if I pass in an array of requests(like $q.all(calls).then(response)), the returned promises are in an array in the **same** order as the calls are passed in? Can I do something like `response[0]` to retrieve the response data returned by the 0th call? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'd suggest just giving it a try.

Comment: Closely related: [order in `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28066429/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that if I pass in an array of requests(like $q.all(calls).then(response)), the returned promises are in an array in the same order as the calls are passed in? Can I do something like response[0] to retrieve the response data returned by the 0th call?

Yes, the results in an array are returned in the same order:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($q) {
     var promise99 = $q.when(99);
     var promise22 = $q.when(22);
     
     $q.all([promise22,promise99]).then(function([result22,result99]) {
         console.log(result22);
         console.log(result99);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app"></body>
```

### `$q.all` Also Accepts Hashes

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($q) {
     var promise99 = $q.when(99);
     var promise22 = $q.when(22);

     var promiseHash = {
         r99: promise99,
         r22: promise22
     };
     
     $q.all(promiseHash).then(function(resultHash) {
         console.log(resultHash.r22);
         console.log(resultHash.r99);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app"></body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)