# Async/Await in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have a react component that runs this function on the mounting of the component.

```
 function getListOfItems(){
    let result = [];
    for(let i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        /**
         * code to assign values to some variables namely param1,param2
         */
        getDetails(param1,param2);
    }
    const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
        let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
        result.push(list);
        if(result.length === 5){
            //code to update a hook which causes render and displays the text in results array
        }
    }
 }
  
 useEffect(() => {
   getListOfItems()
 },[])
```

So the code is running but the **results** array has data in random order. For instance, the results array might look something like this **[2,5,1,3,4]** where I expect it to be like this **[1,2,3,4,5]** This means the above code is not running async tasks in the order of their arrival. So could someone help me out to fix this, I want the code to make async requests in order of their arrival.

Comment: I know I could refactor the code, such that I'll store all required params in an array and later make API calls by iterating over that, but I would like to know if there are any simpler solutions possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `await` keyword again to wait for each iteration of the loop to complete before it moves on to the next go-round.

```js
await getDetails(param1,param2)
```

But as you can only do this in an async function, your `getListOfItems` will also need to be an async function.

```
async function getListOfItems(){
    let result = [];
    for(let i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        await getDetails(param1,param2);
    }
    const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
        let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
        result.push(list);
        if(result.length === 5){}
    }
 }
```

Comment: There's no reason to use a side-efect-ful function vs. just returning the list and pushing in the `for`.

Comment: That's a good point...It could all be wrapped inside the `for` loop, and the `getDetails` function done away with.  Though I'm not sure if @karthik had any other plans for that function, or the `if` statement in there, that he may have wanted to tease out into some other function for whatever reason.  Good point though

Comment: Yup, or `getDetails` could be defined at a higher scope so it was reusable, etc. But yeah, it depends a bit on more context than we have. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> So the code is running but the results array has data in random order.

That's because your loop calls `getDetails` repeatedly **without** waiting for the previous call to complete. So all the calls overlap and race.

If it's okay that they overlap but you need the results in order, use `Promise.all` and have `getDetails` return its results (rather than pushing them directly).

If you **can't** make `getListOfItems` an `async` function:

```
const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
    let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
    if(result.length === 5){
        //code to update a hook which causes render and displays the text in results array
    }
    return list;
}
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    promises.push(getDetails(param1, param2));
}
Promise.all(promises)
.then(results => {
    // `results` is an array of the results, in the same order as the
    // array of promises
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

If you **can** (and the caller will handle any error that's propagated to it via rejection of the promise from `getListOfItems`):

```
const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
    let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
    if(result.length === 5){
        //code to update a hook which causes render and displays the text in results array
    }
    return list;
}
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    promises.push(getDetails(param1, param2));
}
const results = await Promise.all(promises)
// `results` is an array of the results, in the same order as the
// array of promises
```

---

If you need them not to overlap but instead to run one after another, your best bet is to use an `async` function for the loop.

If you **can't** make `getListOfItems` an `async` function:

```
const getAllResults = async function() {
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        results.push(await getDetails(param1, param2));
    }
    return results;
}
const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
    let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
    if(result.length === 5){
        //code to update a hook which causes render and displays the text in results array
    }
    return list;
}
getAllResults()
.then(results => {
    // `results` is an array of the results, in order
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

If you **can** (and the caller will handle any error that's propagated to it via rejection of the promise from `getListOfItems`):

```
const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    results.push(await getDetails(param1, param2));
}
// Use `results
const getDetails = async (param1,param2) => {
    let list = await getAPIresults(param1)
    if(result.length === 5){
        //code to update a hook which causes render and displays the text in results array
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I've learnt a new thing, but making the function that has for loop seems  simpler but the other one might also be useful

Comment: @karthik- The second code block above shows a simple `for` loop (and your `getDetails` function, since I had to tweak it). In general, you want to avoid side-effect-based logic and prefer returning things. For one thing, it would mean you could put `getDetails` somewhere and reuse it rather than recreating it every time so it closes over the right `results` array.  But it's up to you! Happy coding. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `Promise.all`; this would preserve the order as well:

[Promise.all: Order of resolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066429/promise-all-order-of-resolved-values)