# async/await variable asigns inside a map funcition is not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

In a map I'm asigning the results of an async/await function from a db query, but I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work, my code:

```
arr.map(async(each,i)=>{
  await es.getData(each.indexElastic, each[0].attributes.field_query).then(res=>auxJson.queries[i][`results${i}`] = res)
```

It supose to generate a json like this:

```
{
 queries:[
  {results0: res},
  {results1: res},
  {results2: res},
  ...
 ]
}
```

The response is ok, inside the map all is good, but outside the map nothing is assigned to the auxJson. I also try with Promise.all and assign everything in the then() of the Promise.all.

What is wrong?

I did this:

```
let promises = arr.map((each,i)=>{ return es.getData(each.indexElastic, each[0].attributes.field_query) });

let result = Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
        return res.flat(1);
    });
result.then(res=>res.map((answer,i)=>auxJson.queries[i][`results${i}`] = answer))
```

And also doesn't work...

Comment: `.map()` does not understand `async` callbacks, so the result of the `.map()` will be an array of Promise objects. Your code has to `await` that array with `Promise.all()` or some other similar solution.

Comment: Also, as posted your `.map()` callback does not have a `return` so you'll end up with an array of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something like this :

```
    let promises = arr.map((each,i)=>{ return es.getData(each.indexElastic, each[0].attributes.field_query) });

    let result = await Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
        return res.flat(1);
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Don't forget to put this into an async function ;)

Comment: I did ```result.then(res=>res.map((answer,i)=>auxJson.queries[i][`results${i}`] = answer))```, and that doesn't work my json doesn't have the new key with the results...

Comment: This is whatI get   ```Promise { <pending> }```  if i make a ```console.log(result)``` , thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh ,it's my bad I miss read my code, I will update this

Comment: I'm in an infinite loop returning the Promise XD

Comment: Can you share the result you get from this code ?

Comment: My problem was that I didn't write an await, the code has too many async and awaits, sorry and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
let results = await Promise.all(
  arr.map(elem => queryDB(elem))
)
```

Comment: You of course meant `Promse.all()`.

Comment: No, because Promise.all shuffles the returned array depending on the time used to query the ressource. So using Promise.allSettled you can retreive which is which using the index of the first array and avoid some shenanigans.

Comment: `Promise.all()` does [preserve order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066851/5648954), there is no shuffling.

Comment: I did result.then(res=>res.map((answer,i)=>auxJson.queries[i][`results${i}`] = answer)), and that doesn't work my json doesn't have the new key with the results...

Comment: I think you are using a way too complex syntax to do this..
What is the output of console.log(results) when you use my answer : 
let results = await Promise.all(
  arr.map(elem => queryDB(elem))
) ?